# No option to print LibreOffice Base document

Tags: windows, printing, libreoffice-base

My husband is trying to print out a document he has produced in LibreOffice Base.

Unfortunately there is no option to print and we have tried everything we can think of. Bit of a Luddite so please explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing the ctrl+P . its a common key in most of the application for printing.

if it does not work then print option must be in file menu.

Comment: The link you posted is for LibreOffice Impress, not LibreOffice Base.

Comment: so that ctrl+p is not working ? also what version you are using

Comment: It's not me who had the problem, I was just pointing out that you were using the wrong link.

Comment: ooPs! i forget to check name. :)

Answer (score 0):

A database is actually a collection of several of these items:

- tables
- queries
- forms
- reports

Of those, only the last two (forms and reports) can be printed. If there's no Print command under the File menu, then perhaps you are trying to print a table or a query.

You can easily create a form/report from a table/query using the available wizards and selecting the information you want them to include.

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks like this is indeed the problem. He's still insisting he printed from tables before. Lol. But I think I can now sort him out and get on with my knitting! Lol X

Comment: Although it is better to print a form, you can export a table to a Calc sheet for printing. Open a blank spreadsheet, open the base table. Click on the field title bar of the table to the left of the first field so that all the table is selected. Hold down the button and drag the table into the spreadsheet and it will be copied there. You can print the table from a query result the same way.